# Python import sounddevice as sd (ImportError: No module name sounddevice)

Tags: python, audio

I have python code that is running on raspberry pi B++ that uses the sounddevice library that lets you play and record sounds with python. I have successfully installed the modules. I can confirm through the python command line and enter import sounddevice as sd is works without errors. I have also confirmed by typing help ('modules') in python command line and sounddevice module appears. Only when I am running this code in an independent python program does the  ImportError: No module name sounddevice appear.

Hope some one can help.

Here is the included code:

import sounddevice as sd

The error:

ImportError: No module name sounddevice

Comment: Sounddevice  provides bindings for the PortAudio library , Can you confirm if you have resolved dependencies as listed at `http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.1/` . There is dependency of `portaudio` before installing sounddevice?

Comment: So after doing more research I read it says PyAudio provides Python bindings for PortAudio. I did install pyaudio and the module does not  show up saying its not installed. Very strange !

Comment: Hello After alot of trail and error I final solved it on the pip install sounddevice --user . You need to remove  --user part . so that the command is: pip install sounddevice . This installs it through out the entire system and works.

Answer (score 9):

Hello After alot of trial and error I final solved it on the `pip install sounddevice --user`.

**You need to remove `--user` part** so that the command is: **`pip install sounddevice`** . This installs it through out the entire system and works.

Answer (score 1):

Install **sounddevice** using pip from **anaconda** prompt:

open anaconda prompt and type in :

```
pip install sounddevice --user
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on Windows 10 even after eliminating the --user part of the pip install command.  For some reason, installing pyaudio first resolved the problem with sounddevice.  Sounddevice continues to work even after uninstalling pyaudio.  They're both based on Portaudio so perhaps there's something shared in there, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed `sounddevice` module. It was giving me errors constantly while installing it using `pip`. So, I had to install it using `conda` in the desired environment separately. You can follow the given procedure.

Step 1: Open Anaconda Prompt. (Install Anaconda in case you don't have it)

Step 2: Type the following to get all the environments

```
conda env list
```

Step 3: Move into the environment you want to install `sounddevice`

```
conda activate name_of_any_desired_env
```

For Example:

```
conda activate mytestenv
```

Step 4: Install `sounddevice` using one of the following commands. You have to try all the commands in case the first one does not work for you.

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-sounddevice
```

OR

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 python-sounddevice
```

OR

```
 conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 python-sounddevice
```

OR

```
 conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 python-sounddevice
```

The very first worked for me, and I am using it on Python 3.7.

[image]

You can check [this official page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-sounddevice) for installing the latest version